# Create json object with multiple array in c#

Tags: c#, json

I want to create JSON object with following format:-

```
{
  "result": [
      {
        "name": "John",
        "address": "US",
      },
      {
        "name": "Josh",
        "address": "Japan",
      }
  ],
  "error": [
    {
      "message": "error-message"
    }
  ],
  "success": [
    {
      "message": "success-message"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried the following, but it doesn't help me.

```
dynamic record = new { result = new {name="", address=""},
                   error = new {message=""},
                   success = new {message=""} };
```

**Update 1:-**

Here is my code:-
        List addressList = new List();

```
  // Loop over items within the container and URI.
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        dynamic record = new { result = new object[] {
    new {name = item.name, address = item.address} } };
        addressList.Add(record);

    }
```

Result:-

```
[  {
    "result": [
      {
        "name": "John",
        "address": "US"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "result": [
      {
        "name": "Jack",
        "address": "CA"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Expected json result:-

```
  [{
        "result": [{
            "name": "John",
            "address": "US"
        }]
    },
    {
        "result": [{
            "name": "Jack",
            "address": "CA"
        }],
        "error": [{
            "message": "error-message"
        }],
        "success": [{
            "message": "success-message"
        }]
    }
]
```

How do I update my code to get above expected json result?

Answer (score 5):

You...create arrays. You're not doing that. You're creating individual objects.

Something along the lines of:

```
dynamic record = new {
    result = new object[] {
        new {name = "John", address = "US"},
        new {name = "Josh", address = "Japan"}
    },
    error = new object[] /*...*/,
    success = new object[] /*...*/
};
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Its works. But I am new to c#, how can I add message to error and success array?

Comment: @karan: Just like with the entries in the `result` array. `message` instead of `name`, and just the one property instead of two, and that's it.

Comment: I want error and message should be common for entire payload. But I am getting like this     {
    "result": [
      {
        "name": "John",
        "address": "US"
      }
    ],
    "error": [
      {
        "message": ""
      }
    ],
    "success": [
      {
        "message": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "result": [
      {
        "name": "Jack",
        "address": "Cananda"
      }
    ],
    "error": [
      {
        "message": ""
      }
    ],
    "success": [
      {
        "message": ""
      }
    ]
  }
]

Answer (score 2):

If you want exactly JSON, then **newtonsoft.Json** makes it easier:

```
Json json = new Json();

json.result = new object[] {
    new {name = "John", address = "US"},
    new {name = "Josh", address = "Japan"}
};
// json.error = ... and so on

string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
```

The output you will have is:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "name": "John",
      "address": "US",
    },
    {
      "name": "Josh",
      "address": "Japan",
    }
  ],
  "error": [
    {
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

To deserialize it back, use:

```
Json deserializedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Json>(output);
```

Comment: .Net's own JavaScriptSerializer is also perfectly happy with raw input in the style of the OP's.

Answer (score 1):

**The Model Class**

```
public class MegaMenu
    {
        public int department_id { get; set; }
        public string department_name { get; set; }
        public List<SectionListData> sectionListData { get; set; }
    }
    public class SectionListData 
    {
        public int section_id { get; set; }
        public string section_name { get; set; }
        public List<ItemHeadList> itemHeadList { get; set; }
    }
    public class ItemHeadList
    {
        public int item_head_id { get; set; }
        public string item_name { get; set; }
    }
    public class WrapperMegaMenu
    {
        public List<MegaMenu> megaMenuList { get; set; }
        public string error { get; set; }
    }
```

**The Services**

> dept_result is the array of all department,section_result is the array of all section,Item_result is the array of all items

```
List<MegaMenu> listmenu = new List<MegaMenu>();
            foreach (var each_dept in dept_result)
            {
                MegaMenu megaMenu = new MegaMenu();
                megaMenu.department_id = each_dept.shopdepartment_id;
                megaMenu.department_name = each_dept.name_en;
                var temSectionList = section_result
                .Where(item => item.shopdepartment_id == each_dept.shopdepartment_id).ToList().Select(sectionData => new SectionListData
                {
                    section_id = sectionData.shopsection_id,
                    section_name = sectionData.name_en,
                    itemHeadList = Item_result.Where(itemHead => itemHead.shopsection_id == sectionData.shopsection_id).ToList().Select(itemHeadData => new ItemHeadList {
                        item_head_id = itemHeadData.item_head_id,
                        item_name = itemHeadData.name_en
                    }).ToList()
                }).ToList();
                megaMenu.sectionListData = temSectionList;
                listmenu.Add(megaMenu);
            }
            //wrapperDept.departmentList = dept_result.ToList();

            wrapper.megaMenuList = listmenu.ToList();
```

**Result**

```
{
    "megaMenuList": [
        {
            "department_id": 71,
            "department_name": "Baby's Hygiene",
            "sectionListData": [
                {
                    "section_id": 56,
                    "section_name": "Diapers",
                    "itemHeadList": []
                },
                {
                    "section_id": 57,
                    "section_name": "Wipes",
                    "itemHeadList": [
                        {
                            "item_head_id": 142,
                            "item_name": "Telivision"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you  are not creating an array
if you want to create `JSON` arrays from  c#  you have to use the following POCO

```
public class Result
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
}

public class Error
{
    public string message { get; set; }
}

public class Success
{
    public string message { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Result> result { get; set; }
    public List<Error> error { get; set; }
    public List<Success> success { get; set; }
}
```

and then  use Json.net

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( "your instance of the root Object")
```

Comment: All of that infrastructure is only useful if you're interacting with this on the C# side. You don't need any of it just to create the desired JSON and send it off somewhere.

Comment: that's true but remains the simplest and cleanest way to do it in c#  or does'nt  ?

Comment: No, not remotely. See my answer. The OP just said he/she wants to create JSON. Didn't say anything about needing C# classes to interact with the object structure before making the JSON.

Comment: Yes, you certainly don't need to use Json.Net everywhere

Comment: Ok let's agree that creating a dynamic object is the fastest way but in an application, we deal with POCO and doing So we are less error prone

Answer (score 0):

//You need to make this class structure first

```
public class Response
{
    public List<Result> result { get; set; }
    public List<Error> error { get; set; }
    public List<Success> success { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
}

public class Error
{
    public string message { get; set; }
}

public class Success
{
    public string message { get; set; }
}
```

// And then you can use it like this

```
        var response = new Response()
        {
            result = new List<Result>
            {
                new Result() {name = "Jhon", address = "US"},
                new Result() {name = "Jhon", address = "US"},
            },
            error = new List<Error>()
            {
                new Error() {message = "error-message 1"},
                new Error() {message = "error-message 2"}
            },
            success = new List<Success>()
            {
                new Success(){message = "success-message 1"},
                new Success(){message = "success-message 2"},
            }
        };
```